# Can I use GitHub to create PRs on remote repos what were not closed?

Tags: git, github

I have two repos, origin O and my own fork C. There is also a remote R which exists on github and is a copy of O but wasn't cloned using the UI. It shares the same commit history. Since O is no longer maintained I'd like to re-open my older PRs on R instead of O.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is what you're referring to as *a personal clone `C`* an actual clone (local repository) or is it a fork on Github?

Comment: Clarified above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to re-open my older PRs on O instead on R.

You can fetch the PR branches, following "[Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)",

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

Then you can push that branch to R.

```
git remote add R /url/of/R
git push -u R BRANCHNAME
```

Then you can open a PR from that remote branch on R.

Comment: I don't have write access to R. So I'd clone R to R' and fetch the branches there?

Comment: @andig To be clear: where do you want to open your PR to? R? If you don't have access to R, fork R, and push to that fork.